# Unexpected answer while using date format in php

Tags: php

I want to get month from date, those dates are taken from database so some dates are in '0000-00-00' format.

//for example I give this below date

```
$arr='0000-00-00';
$thismonth = date('m', strtotime($arr));
echo $thismonth;
```

//here I expecting 00 or null something but the answer is 11.

Comment: PHP has problems to interpret this date Result: `-0001-11-30`. See https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php. Perhaps it has to deal with, that Gregorian calendar isn't defined for that date

Comment: Unrelated but why do you name a string $arr? Do you enjoy the challenge or something?

Comment: Actually date's are passing as array so I need take date's in month wise, so here some null dates are passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date are never '0000-00-00' or 0 or null , in date function you never enter wrong value
so check

```
$arr='0000-00-00';
if($arr != '0000-00-00'){
$thismonth = date('m', strtotime($arr));
echo $thismonth;
}
else{
$thismonth = '00';
}
```

Comment: In date field, if user forget to enter date. the date in database save like this value-> '0000-00-00'. Then I need to list out those values depend on month so 00 takes as 11